# How to have brightness fade away before display sleeping

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

Gnome and KDE will fade away the brightness little by little before display sleeping, how to get the function to my XFCE or xUbuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Sleep, brightness and other settings can be controlled by the xfce4 Power Manager. https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/preferences

Comment: There is no option about brightness fade away in Power Manager

Comment: What is the end goal here exactly? When you click sleep to have your screen fade out and then sleep instead of just going black momentarily?

Comment: Any difference with `Put to sleep after` and `Swich off after`? In fact the brightness fade out can notice me the screen is going to be locked.